# Unique ID for TaskItem in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, mapi

I'm importing all the tasks from outlook into a database.

To flag those that are different since the last import I need a unique ID for each task item object that does not change.

I've looked at TaskItem.EntryID. The microsoft documentation says it's only unique to each storage location which is fine as these tasks won't be moved.

The trouble is with recurrences:

I make a recurrent task due on 28/05/2019 which has an ID of ..D890000

I complete the task and outlook creates the new task for the next scheduled day.

The original task for 28/05/2019 now has a DIFFERENT ID of ..D8A0000
The new task for 29/05/2019 has the original ID of ..D890000

I have also tried using PR_SEARCH_KEY which is the same across these tasks.

Would anyone be able to tell me how to get a unique ID for each TaskItem that persists.

Or would you be able to confirm that the only time it will change is in the event of recursive tasks?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected - when an instance of a recurring task is completed, Outlook creates a completed task for the current date and advances the existing recurring task to the next day while decrementing the recurrence count.